# Assembling executable code?

Tags: assembly

today I was learning a bit on x86 assembly today and learned a lot of new stuff and I like the language very much but have encountered something that I would like to know if it's possible.

I would like to know if it's possible to only assemble the code, without having an output of an entire executable.

**Now obviously this would not be practical if I had to have to use data like strings and etc,
but what I want to only assemble is code like this:**

```
  mov si, 1
loop:
  inc si
  jnz loop
```

*(I know this this has some stuff missing but that's not the point.)*

I can just assemble this and just find the raw entry point of the code and copy
it as input, however it just seems very hackish in a way I cannot describe with words.

Thank you.

BTW, I'm using FASM.

Comment: «I cannot describe with words»: well, you should at least try to describe a little more what you are trying to achieve... Otherwise, just learn about linkers...

Comment: yes it is possible, that is how assemblers usually work these days.  just assemble it into an object then later you can link it with other objects or you can disassemble it to see what the machine code is that the assembler generated.

Comment: nothing hackish at all about it, this is the normal use for an assembler.  that is what they are there to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, duo to my lack of knowledge with assembly, I figured
you need to have full program in order to make it assemble, but I noticed all I needed
to do is just write down the instructions without anything and it just assembles it into
a .BIN file (I think it's short for binary).